# Send Ajax GET request to PHP and display the response which is an image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image

I have to implement buttons that allow for simple image editing (Grayscale, turning it +/- 90° etc.). I have a selection of images (with a radio button to each) and upon clicking on one of the buttons, I call a function that makes an Ajax GET request with the relative image url and the action called (turn x degrees, grayscale...). PHP successfully receives the call and also sends a response.

Unfortunately, the response data is only gibberish

```
�����JFIF���������>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ���C�...
```

The content-type is set though (and also sent as such, confirmed using Firebug)
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

However, when I check the data that Ajax receives, it just shows the folder structure of my local server (localhost/...) and [object%20Object].

This is the function where I make the request

Javascript in HTML file

```
var selection = document.getElementById('selection').src;
var y = $.get("image.php", { "image": selection, "type" : "jpeg" } );
```

PHP

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['image']);
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Is there any way to make this work? If not, are there any other options I could take? I thought about saving the edited image in a separate folder and only returning the path to it but I way I am trying to do it now seems a little bit easier in terms of getting it to work (at least I thought so...)

Comment: Either send it as a Data: URL (`base64_encode` to encode image data) or store the image somewhere on the server and return a link to it. In both cases you would then, upon receiving an answer from php, create an empty `img` element in DOM, and set it's `src` attribute to either data: url or an image path.

Comment: Why not just set the `image src` to the php file? eg. `$("#myImg").attr("src", "image.php?ìmage="+selection+"&type=jpeg");`

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. It's working. Hopefully it still will after expanding on it.